# How to add profile icon at the top right corner of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a profile icon at the top right corner that should have 'My account' and 'logout' as options like shown in the image.Please let me know how can i add it to the below code.

```
<style type="text/css">


ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#nav {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    padding-right: 1px;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#nav a {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 12px 50px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.logoutLblPos{

   position:fixed;
   right:10px;
   top:5px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2">
      <h1 class="text-center" style="font-family:Colonna MT;font-size:50px;color:ForestGreen ;">Welcome</h1>
      <p class="lead text-center" style="font-size:20px;color:DarkSalmon;"><i>"This is caption"</i></p>

       <label class="logoutLblPos">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="height:50px;width:20px"></span> User
       <input name="submit2" type="submit" id="submit2" value="log out">
  </label>

    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tab4</a></li>
    </ul>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, I need to include "Post your Ad' beside profile icon.

Comment: But you already have it in top-right corner....

Comment: `how to ?` this is not place to ask people to write `code` for you, it's for get help. try it your self and tell us what's your problem.

Comment: @Justinas : Yes, but how can I add "My account" and "logout" as options to it?

Answer (score 0):

Please see example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34rsje2a/)

HTML

```
<div style="background:color:#fff; border:solid 1px #333; float:left; text-align:center; padding:5px;">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i><br>
   User
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you..how about adding options to it? like My account, logout. Am just learning html so didnt know much.